# How to install our window8 app in windows mobile?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows

I am new to windows app.Now i am create new app in vs 2012.It run perfectly in my system.How to install this app to my mobile.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to test your app before publishing to Windows Phone Store you should have valid Developer account and developer unlocked phone. Details are [here](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/join) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

To deploy app from VS2012:

1. Select from runnable options "Device"
2. Connect unlocked phone via USB
3. Unlock lockscreen on device - you should see home screen
4. Press deploy in VS2012
5. Enjoy your app on the phone

If you want to publish your app to Store - follow this [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206736%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)